# Check if username is admin OR is in csv file

Tags: python, csv

I want to check if the input, which is a username, is in the CSV file, and when it is in it, I would like to login with that name:

```
if keuze_11 == "login":
    while True:
        import csv
        csvfile='login.csv'
        try:
            f = open(csvfile, 'r')
            reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=';')
            username = input("Put your username here: ")
            if username == "admin" or username in row[6] of csvfile:
                break
        finally:
            f.close()
```

Can someone help me, cause it won't succeed right now.

Comment: You probably want to move that `import csv` to the beginning of your file, or at least not inside a while loop.

Comment: Where do you define `row` variable?

Comment: Well I am using multiple CSV files so I don't know if that is possible?

Comment: Ah I guess that is the problem? How can I define that?

Comment: You take input as `user` then use `username`, and `username in row[6] of csvfile` isn't really Python. Try refactoring to a separate function e.g. `if in_file(username, csvbestand, 6):`.

Comment: That's because I translated it from dutch to english and I forgot to translate user to username ;) I tried to change it, but then I will get the following error: NameError: name 'in_file' is not defined

Comment: So it is still not working :(

Comment: variable value is used before assignment of variable `in_file`

Comment: Please edit your question to resemble your current code.

Comment: What is the structure of your CSV file? Could you edit your question to include an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a simpler way to make the above work:

```
csv = open('login.csv', 'r').read().split('\n')[6].split(';')
username = input("Put your username here: ")
if username == "admin" or username in csv:
    print "Username Found"
else:
    print "Username Not Found"
```